# How can I set IDE to highlight code lines where I should write 'super' and 'await' on JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The thing is I sometimes forget to write the keywords and VS Code and TypeScript are not willing to notify me that I cannot call an inherited method in class without 'super' and in some cases I should use 'await' with asynchronous function. Please, help me reduce the amount of the errors with your advice.

An example with 'super':

```
class Child{
    printHey(){console.log('Hey')}
}

class Parent extends Child{
    printHey(){
        this.printHey() // the super required
    }
}

new Parent().printHey()
```

An example with 'await':

```
class Echo {
    async getEcho(echo: any){
        return echo
    }

    async printEcho(){
        var echo = 'Hey'
        var message:any = this.getEcho(echo)
        while(message !== echo) 'pass' // The loop got stuck
        console.log(`Echo ${message}`)
    }
}

new Echo().printEcho()
```

Comment: how can typescript know `this.printHey() // the super required` is not intended since it could be recursive call?

Comment: And how can it know whether you want to await the getEcho call? Maybe you want to do something with the Promise?

Comment: It should not know 'await' is required or not. I need to set IDE so that it can highlight or ask me : Sani, here is async function, maybe, you wanna write 'await'.